# how to control data using regular expression and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am have a string like this which come from database.

```
str="This is first string.Exception  No. 1: Unprotected vertical openings in accordance with 8.2.5.8 shall be permitted.Exception  No. 2:Exception  No. 1 to 8.2.5.6(1) shall not apply to patient sleeping and treatment rooms.This is test ".
```

I am using this condtion to break the new line

```
str = str.replace(/(\s\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)/gi, "<br /><br />$1&nbsp");
```

but i get output like this:
      This is first string

```
Exception  No. 1: Unprotected vertical openings in accordance with 8.2.5.8 shall be permitted.

Exception  No. 2:

Exception  No. 1 to 8.2.5.6(1) shall not apply to patient sleeping and treatment rooms.
```

but I want to get output like this:-

```
Exception  No. 1: Unprotected vertical openings in accordance with 8.2.5.8 shall be permitted.

Exception  No. 2:Exception  No. 1 to 8.2.5.6(1) shall not apply to patient sleeping and treatment rooms.
```

This is test.

How can i get this..thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this one :

```
var str = str.replace(/(Exception\s+No\.\s+\d+\:)/g, "<br /><br />$1&nbsp;");
```

Catching the whole starting expression with the `:` avoids catching the citations. Note that I removed the `i` flag, it doesn't seem to be useful.

You were also missing the `;` at the end of `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="Exception  No. 1: Unprotected vertical openings in accordance with"+
        " 8.2.5.8 shall be permitted.Exception  No. 2:Exception  No. 1 to 8.2.5.6(1)"+
        " shall not apply to patient sleeping and treatment rooms.This is test ",
    expected = "<br /><br />Exception  No. 1: Unprotected vertical"+
               " openings in accordance with 8.2.5.8 shall be permitted."+
               "<br /><br />Exception  No. 2:Exception  No. 1 to 8.2.5.6(1)"+
               " shall not apply to patient sleeping and treatment rooms."+
               "This is test ";
str.replace(/(Exception\s+No\.\s*\d\:)/gi,"<br /><br />$1")  === expected
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i have again edited the question. what suppose if condition comes like that..if there is some sentence at the front?

Comment: `This is first string.` will be in the first line, and `Exception  No. 1...` will be on the next